# Access the injectee component from bean factory

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

Suppose we have a prototype-scoped bean.

```
public class FooConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public Foo foo(@Autowired Bar bar) {
    return new Foo(bar);
  }
}
```

We're injecting this bean to a class, `TheDependent`.

```
@Component
public class TheDependent {
  @Autowired
  private Foo foo;
}
```

But there is also another one.

```
@Component
public class AnotherOne {
  @Autowired
  private Foo foo;
}
```

In each `@Autowired`, a new instance of `Foo` gets created because it's annotated with `@Scope("prototype")`.

I would like to access the 'dependent' class from the factory method, `FooConfiguration#foo(Bar)`. Is it possible? Can Spring inject me some sort of *context* object to the parameters of the factory method, providing information about the point of injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can inject `DefaultListableBeanFactory` which is the spring bean container containing all the bean informations to the parameters of the bean factory method :

```
  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public Foo foo(@Autowired Bar bar , DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
         //Get all the name of the dependent bean of this bean
         for(String dependentBean : beanFactory.getDependentBeans("foo")){
              //Get the class of each dependent bean
              beanFactory.getType(dependentBean);

         }
        return new Foo(bar);
  }
```

Comment: That was what I was asking for. Spot on!